# How to set Image in JLabel using getScaledInstance?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I created a Java program using `JFrame` using Window Builder on Eclipse IDE.

In this program I want to set an image in `JLabel` and it will automatically take the image height and width according to the height and width of the `JLabel`.

But it shows me errors like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero
at java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(Unknown Source)
at round.<init>(round.java:292)
```

I've tried in various ways but it shows errors every time.

My code of the `Image` is given below:

```
    lblimg = new JLabel("");
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/demo.jpg"));
    Image img = ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(lblimg.getWidth(), lblimg.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ii = new ImageIcon(img);
    lblimg.setIcon(ii);
    lblimg.setBounds(239, 297, 116, 65);
    contentPane.add(lblimg);
```

Comment: Use ImageIO to read the Image file. You will get an error message if the image is not found. Also, don't use setBounds(). This implies you are using a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: If code calls `new ImageIcon(URL)` the image linked will be loaded asynchronously. Typically we'd use `ImageIO.read(..)` intead, which blocks while the image is loaded. Making sure the it's fully loaded, should correct the image width and height being 0.

Comment: How to use this? can you explain please? I Don't know about this.

Comment: *I Don't know about this* - How do you learn so use any class? Normally you read the API and/or  search the site/web for examples that use the ImageIO class.

Comment: See [ImageIO.read(URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)) for the details.

Comment: BTW: `lblimg.setBounds(239, 297, 116, 65);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I Understand. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for helping